# How to tell Cloud ML engine to install SWIG?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, box2d, swig, google-cloud-ml, openai-gym

I'm facing a RL problem which uses Box2D package and I want to do some computations using Google's AI platform. I made a  *setup.py*  file:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['gym>=0.11.0', 'box2d-py==2.3.8', 'box2d-kengz==2.3.3']

setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='My training application package.'
)
```

and then I use the command

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME   --package-path trainer/   --module-name trainer.ppo_lstm_joined   --region $REGION   --python-version 3.5   --runtime-version 1.13   --job-dir $JOB_DIR   --stream-logs
```

but Box2D package won't install, because it requires SWIG. It is easy to install it on my PC, but how do I tell the cloud to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file structure is correct:

[image]

More information in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/packaging-trainer#manual-build)
If after this, you find the same issue, can you take a look at the logs of the training job?

We have a sample application [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/tensorflow/standard/reinforcement_learning/rl_on_gcp_demo/setup.py) which installs the same packages.